# How to resize application's window

Tags: 20.04

I'm new to ubuntu, when i watch video tutorials, i see how users resize windows via hotkeys, for example terminal, they press some buttons and it is resizing for like 10-20%, please tell me how to do that

Comment: If you have watched videos of how to do it have you not tried what you saw?

Comment: I don't know what buttons they're using, I know it is possible to resize the window's size by clicking ALT + F8 etc, but it is not the same

Answer (score 0):

Each desktop environment has it's own shortcuts to resize windows, on XFCE you do so with ALT+F11 for full-screen, ALT+F8 to resize and so on.

If you're on Unity you can go to Setting -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts Tab -> Windows and change them.

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

to be able to bind more keys to more actions you can install `compizconfig-settings-manager` using `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.